# How to get db reference in the exception catch?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I need to close and delete the current indexeddb when there is an exception
the lines of code look like bellow,

```
export async function getCurrUser(window) {
    ...

    let openRequest = indexedDB.open('userData',2);
    openRequest.onsuccess =  e => {
       let db = e.target.result;//this is not accessable in the catch block
        try{}
        catch(e){
            //close db and delete it. but I cannot get db reference here
            //I can't db.close() here
        }
    };
}
```

Are ther any effective ways to get db in the exception catch?

Comment: Please post more of the code. Your `db` variable is accessible in the catch block, so it looks like something else is the cause of your confusion here, but without seeing more of the code it is difficult to determine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `finally` (always executes) and control it with a boolean:

```
export async function getCurrUser(window) {
...

let openRequest = indexedDB.open('userData',2);
let error = false;
openRequest.onsuccess =  e => {
   let db = e.target.result;//this is not accessable in the catch block
    try{}
    catch(e){
         error = true;
        //print exception
    }finally{
      if (error){
      db.close();
      }
   }
};
}
```

For more info : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I need is "closing the db only when errors are caught." If finally is used here, the db is closed even when no error occurs.

Comment: I found that if the let db = e.target.result; is in the try block, then catch cannot use the db variable. So when I keep this line outside try block and the variable db is accessable in the catch block. So this solution+moving db.close to the catch block works.

Comment: So now what you use ``finally`` for? In my personal preference I would a create boolean and use it for closing the ``db`` in the finally block.

Comment: I see. I don't have a finally block now. I put db.close in catch.